# Show that $\sum_{N-1}^{k=0} \left | F_{k} \right |^{2} = \frac{2N^{2} + 3N + 1}{6}$ for DFT coefficients $F_{k}$

Tags: fourier-transform

Let $F_{k}$ be the DFT of the sequence $1, 2, ..., N$. Show that

$$\sum_{N-1}^{k=0} \left | F_{k} \right |^{2} = \frac{2N^{2} + 3N + 1}{6}$$

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: One way you could do it would be to note a relationship between the norm of the DFT and of the original sequence (do you know the relationship?), and use [the fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3093680/mathematical-induction-for-sum-of-squares) that $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 +\cdots  + N^2 = \frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth thanks for the sum of squares tip, that was very helpful! I noticed that $f_{n}$ would be equal to $[1:N]$. However, I have trouble isolating $e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}$ out. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: You probably don't need to worry about that, you can just use the result here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156356/prove-that-normf-frac1n-normf-dft.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I wish I could upvote you. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome! $\ddot{\smile}$